# Combine these mysql queries from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

Let say I have a table with a list of users, and I retrieve the users table like this:

```
SELECT userid FROM users WHERE year = 2012
```

That generates a list of users, more specifically, userid's (digits).

So, lets say our list looks like this now (random userids):

```
1234
9532
0983
2098
1980
```

In other table, we have the users favorite colors, one entry for each color. So user 1234 could have multiple entries in the table (lets call it fav_colors):

```
1234 red
1234 blue
9532 yellow
9532 red
0983 blue
0983 purple
```

This is very simplified example of a concept I am trying to grasp. How can I form one query to show me the users where the year is 2012 (from the first query), and who likes the color red? I am having trouble combining the queries from the users table and the fav_colors table

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This should get you the results you're looking for

```
SELECT u.userid, c.color
FROM users AS u
JOIN fav_colors AS c
  ON u.userid = c.userid
WHERE u.year = 2012
  AND c.color_name = 'red'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SQL Joins to link both tables and use a where clause for the year and the red color.

See : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp for more info on SQL Joins.

Tell me if you need more explanations.